# My question is about Druid Real Time Ingestion

Tags: druid

I am able to ingest real time data using Tranquility in Druid. But only problem I am facing that I can query rows in druid but when real time process is stopped the newly created datasource is gone and I can 0.0 kb in data sources.

What could be the reason?

Comment: please show your code, there are a lot of things that can go wrong, so hard to start guessing without the code

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by decreasing the granularity from Day to Minutes. I was able to load the data for real time.